# How to query custom object fields value and sum them before opportunity page load, Salesforce?

Tags: controller, opportunity, visualforce

I have two Custom Objects:

1. BigMachines Quotes ( Not Allowed to make any changes in this custom object )
2. Phoenix Quotes

I Need to query values of Total from both custom object, sum them and set the result to Opportunity custom field "BM/PHX Amount" before opportunity page load.

please see attachment

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more detail? What you mean by "should be on Object load, not page load"?

Comment: I added more details, please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two option to call am **Apex-method** before page load:

1. Call any method in the controller's constructor
2. Use an action function in `<apex:page action="{!yourActionFunction}">`

If you just want to call a **JavaScript-method** before page load, just put in a `<script>` tag in the beginning of your markup. It will be executed very early.

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that the `action` attribute of the page only executes on http `GET`. Subsequent calls to the page perform http `POST` unless explicitly forced to `GET`. Best to read up on order of execution here: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_lifecycle.htm

Comment: In case the relations are only lookups the calculations could be made in the constructor. If you need something updating dynamically without submitting the page, JavaScript is the smartest way.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to Roll up total of primaries from 2 different child objects of Opportunity to Opportunity level.

If yes - Create two roll up summary fields (On Opportunity) one corresponding to each object and apply criteria to roll up only when primary = true.

Create one formula field called "Primary Totals" (On Opportunity)  that will be sum of above two fields.

The whole Javascript and VF approach is really complicated one here.

Now if the relationship is not master detail, go for an Apex Trigger!

Cheers,

Comment: it's good idea but I have one problem , I'm not allowed to make any changes in one of custom objects, (I can't add fields or any other things)

Comment: As said by @GariEpranos you need no custom fields on the custom objects but on the standard object **opportunity**. I only recommend the VF/JS approaches because at the time of my answer the question was only about how to call a method before pageload. Since the question was edited and if you can add field to opportunity and if the relations are master-detail, this solution using Rollup Summary Fields should be preferred.

Comment: +1 Uwe, considering the updated question, I think this should be preferred as it will be robust approach! Even if you are not allowed to created fields on Master(Opportunity), you should push hard to get the permission, Your thought Gary ?